# What's the advantage of "If with a short statement"

Tags: if-statement, go

What's the advantage of using an "If with a short statement" in go lang. ref: [go tour](http://tour.golang.org/#23)

```
if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {
    return v
}
```

Instead of just write the statement before the `if`.

```
v := math.Pow(x, n)
if v < lim {
    return v
}
```

Comment: What @VonC said. Most of the time I prefer the second form because it clearly separates an action ("calculate the power of `x` to `n`) from checking ("check if v is within the certain limit") while the first form mixes both makin the `math.Pow()` look as if it has been calculated only to check the result and then throw it away.

Comment: Ita has sense now. The scope of 'if', so there are different in that sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim` is interesting **if you don't need '`v`' outside of the scope of '`if`'**.

It is mentioned in "[Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#if)"

> Since `if` and `switch` accept an initialization statement, it's common to see one used to set up a local variable.

```
if err := file.Chmod(0664); err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
    return err
}
```

The second form allows for '`v`' to be used after the `if` clause.

The **true difference is in the scope where you need this variable**: defining it within the `if` clause allows to keep the scope where that variable is used to a minimum.

Comment: 4 line form is actually 1 character shorter `\n` vs `; `

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood yes, I insist on the *actual* difference at the end of my answer: it is all about scope, not number of characters ;)